# How to write multiple xtabs in a CSV file?

Tags: r, csv

For writing a single xtab, I have used:

```
write.csv(xtabData1, "analysis.csv")
```

For appending one more xtab to the same csv file, I tried:

```
write.csv(xtabData2, "analysis.csv", append=T)
```

But this throws a warning "attempt to set 'append' ignored" and overwrites the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to join the tab data first using `rbind`, e.g.

```
write.csv(rbind(xtabData1, xtabData2), file="analysis.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `append` option is disabled in `write.csv()`. `write.csv()` is just a wrapper function for `write.table()`. Here;s more from the help file.

> write.csv and write.csv2 provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV
>   files. They set sep and dec (see below), qmethod = "double", and
>   col.names to NA if row.names = TRUE (the default) and to TRUE
>   otherwise. write.csv uses "." for the decimal point and a comma for
>   the separator. write.csv2 uses a comma for the decimal point and a
>   semicolon for the separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in
>   some Western European locales. **These wrappers are deliberately
>   inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions
>   are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change append, col.names,
>   sep, dec or qmethod are ignored, with a warning.**

Use `write.table()` instead (with `sep=","` and whatever other settings you'd like).